# Issue when converting odoo 9 code in to Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have a module developed for online payments. As Odoo 10 has released with a new API I have converted this in to the new API. But when I install / update my addon I have an xml parse error in my xml file.

```
ParseError: "File not found: payment_gateway/static/src/img/gateway_icon.png" while parsing file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Odoo%2010.0e/server/odoo/addons/payment_gateway/data/payment_acquirer_data.xml:5, near
<record id="payment.payment_acquirer_gateway" model="payment.acquirer">
        **<field name="name">gateway</field>**
        <field name="image" type="base64" file="payment_gateway/static/src/img/gateway_icon.png"/>
        <field name="provider">gateway</field>
        <field name="company_id" ref="base.main_company"/>
        <field name="view_template_id" ref="gateway_acquirer_button"/>
        <field name="environment">test</field>
        <field name="pre_msg">
&lt;p&gt;You will be redirected to the website after clicking on the payment button.&lt;/p&gt;</field>
        <field name="gateway_merchant_number">dummy</field>
</record>
```

[Above code in a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2kxA.png)

Does anyone can point me the reason.
Thanks

Comment: First of all, is the file `gateway_icon.png` in place and with the right permissions? Is the module `payment_gateway` in your addons_path?

Comment: I have to agree with @GeorgeD, probably permissions or the existence of the file at all in that location. I am guessing your addon is in the correct path or this xml file would never have been parsed (albeit with errors) at all.

Comment: Got fixed that by correcting the path